unable to generate bin folder using bash script with command: cmake -B build/Debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug; cmake --build build/Debug -j8
the bin folder inside build/Debug is generated in local environment (in vscode) by building the project using ctl+shift+b.
like that in below image using
command:
cmake -B ${workspaceFolder}/X2/build/Debug -S ${workspaceFolder}/X2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug;cmake --build ${workspaceFolder}/X2/build/Debug -j8


Now when the same command:
cmake -B build/Debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug; cmake --build build/Debug -j8

I am executing in bash script the bin folder under build/Debug is not generating. Why this happening??
bash script file:
#!/bin/bash
# Set the library output path
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH="${PWD}/Local_Build/Lib"
# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"

pwd
cmake -B build/Debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug; cmake --build build/Debug -j8

I need help.

Please [edit] your question and show the output of your script. Are you sure you checked the correct location? The command in the script is not the same. cmake -B ${workspaceFolder}/X2/build/Debug... vs cmake -B build/Debug.... The part ${workspaceFolder}/X2/ might result in a different location.

Nothing in the code you show tells CMake to create bin/ subdirectory. Probably, your project sets CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/bin, in that case given subdirectory will be automatically created with creation of an executable or a shared library.

It smells like you describe the XY problem: you get some other error and think that it is caused by non-created bin/ subdirectory. Instead of focusing on non-existent directory only, it is better to share your original error (problem).

@Bodo location is correct.  "The command in the script is not the same" - it's same only I am using pwd that's why.

@Tsyvarev if code compile successfully then bin/ will be generated successfully.
